# python - how to properly format a string inorder to pass in as a variable

Tags: python

I'm getting the error:
 `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

when trying to pass this string, `hummer` to a variable `%s` that which is passed into the `subprocess` module like so:

```
import subprocess

mydim="hummer"
mycat=int(subprocess.check_output('cat dump_cars_tbl.out | grep -i %s | wc -l', shell=True) % mydim)

if mycat > 0:
    print ('Yes')
else:
    print ('No')
```

How do I properly pass in this string to a variable?

Comment: First thing, remove your `try`/`finally` block so you can see the actual exception that is getting raised.

Comment: I did that. Now, i'm getting the `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` and I cannot figure that out.

Comment: Yup. You've got your `% mydim` in the wrong place. Put it after the last `'` of your command line string.

Comment: I placed like so: `mycat=int(subprocess.check_output('cat dump_cars_tbl.out | grep -i %s | wc -l', % mydim, shell=True)` - `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of that line.

Comment: Sorry. Still an issue even with the missing `)` - `mycat=int(subprocess.check_output('cat dump_cars_tbl.out | grep -i %s | wc -l', % mydim, shell=True))` - `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You also have a comma before the `% mydim` - remove that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Syntax error on my part. Please provide your answer and I can use that. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot add an answer because this question is marked as a duplicate. Just smile and move on. :)